# Formulating the variational principle in grand canonical ensemble

Tags: statistical-mechanics, mathematical-physics, variational-principle

After a very nice discussion in my [previous question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/775840/variational-principle-for-canonical-ensemble), I decided to move on and try to formulate the variational principle for the grand canonical ensemble. I tried following the references cited in the answer to my post, but I don't seem to be getting anywhere, probably because of different approaches and notations.

My setting is the following. The phase space now is $\Omega_{N} := (\Lambda \times \mathbb{R}^{d})^{N}$ for some $N \ge 1$ and $\Lambda \subset \mathbb{R}^{d}$ nonempty and compact. Equip $\Omega_{N}$ with its Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathbb{B}_{N}$. Let $\mu_{\Lambda,\beta,z}^{(N)}$ be the measure on $(\Omega_{N},\mathbb{B}_{N})$ with has the following density with respect to the Lebesgue measure:
$$d\mu_{\Lambda,\beta,z}^{(N)} := \frac{1}{N!}z^{N}e^{-\beta H_{\Lambda,\beta}^{(N)}(x)}dx$$
where $z \in \mathbb{R}$ is a parameter e $H_{\Lambda,\beta}^{(N)}$ an $N$-body Hamiltonian. Here, I am assuming $\mu_{\Lambda,\beta,z}^{(0)}(\{\emptyset\}) = 1$.

Set $\Omega := \bigcup_{N=0}^{\infty}(\Omega_{N}\times \{N\})$, where I am assuming $\Omega_{0} = \{\emptyset\}$ for simplicity. For each $E \in \mathbb{B}_{N}$, let $\pi_{N}(E) := \{x \in \Omega_{N}: (x,N) \in E\}$.  We equip $\Omega$ with the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$, defined by:
$$\mathcal{F}:= \{E \subset \Omega: \mbox{$\pi_{N}(E) \in \mathbb{B}_{N}$ for every $N \in \mathbb{N}$}\}$$
We introduce a probability measure $\mu_{\Lambda,\beta,z}$ on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ by setting:
$$\mu_{\Lambda,\beta,z} := \frac{1}{Z_{\Lambda,\beta,z}}\sum_{N=0}^{\infty}\mu_{\Lambda,\beta,z}^{(N)}$$
where the partition function $Z_{\Lambda,\beta,z}$ only normalizes the measure.

This is the tricky part for me. The measure $\mu_{\Lambda,\beta,z}$ is supposed to be the Gibbs measure that minimizes a given functional, which coincides with the free energy at its minimum. What is this functional? In principle, it is supposed to be defined over all measures $\mu$ on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$. However, we only defined our objects (e.g. Hamiltonian) on $\Omega_{N}$. In other words, what would something like $\mathbb{E}_{\mu}[H_{\Lambda,\beta}]$ mean? Should I, instead, define the variational principle in terms of all measures $\mu$ on $\Omega$ which have the form $\mu = \sum_{N=0}^{\infty}\mu_{N}$, where $\mu_{N}$ is a measure on $\Omega_{N}$?

Comment: I'll provide an answer if I find time. In the meantime, you might have a look at Section 1.3 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.08105.pdf), which should be readable. The ideas are exactly the same as for the canonical ensemble (but the reference measure is a Poisson point process now rather than Lebesgue).

Comment: @YvanVelenik thank you for this new reference. I am not very familiar with Poisson point processes, but I tried to learn something from it. I sketched an answer of my own question below. I would highly appreciate your comments and/or corrections to it.

Answer (score 1):

*Attempted Proof:* Suppose we have a family $\{f_{N}\}_{N\in \mathbb{N}}$ of functions $f_{N}: \Omega_{N} \to \mathbb{R}$. It induces a function $f: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ by setting
$$f(x,N) := f_{N}(x). \tag{1}\label{1}$$
Hence, we can define the Hamiltonian $H_{\Lambda,\beta}: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ by $H_{\Lambda,\beta}(x,N) := H_{\Lambda,\beta}^{(N)}(x)$.

Let $\delta$ be a counting measure on $\mathbb{N}$, that is, $\delta(\{N\}) = 1$. Let $\mu$ be a measure on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ with density
$$d\mu = \rho(x,N) d\delta dx. \tag{2}\label{2}$$
If $f$ is defined as in (\ref{1}), then expectation with respect to $\mu$ leads to:
$$\mathbb{E}_{\mu}[f] := \int_{\Omega} f(x,N)\rho(x,N)d\delta dx = \sum_{N=0}^{\infty}\int_{\Omega_{N}} f_{N}(x)\rho(x,N)dx \tag{3}\label{3}$$
We denote the set of all measures $\mu$ of the form (\ref{2}) by $\mathcal{M}(\Omega)$.

The entropy functional is now defined by:
$$\mathcal{M}(\Omega) \ni \mu \mapsto S(\mu):= \mathbb{E}_{\mu}[\log\rho] \equiv \sum_{N=0}^{\infty}\int_{\Omega_{N}}\rho(x,N)\log(\rho(x,N))dx \tag{4}\label{4}$$
Thus, the measure $\mu_{\Lambda,\beta,z}$ defined in my post is the solution of:
$$\inf_{\mu \in \mathcal{M}(\Omega)}(\mathbb{E}_{\mu}[H_{\Lambda,\beta}] - TS(\mu) -\mu \mathbb{E}_{\mu}[\mathcal{N}]) \tag{5}\label{5}$$
where $\mathcal{N}(x,N) := N$ is the number function.

Comment: At first glance, this seems fine. One of the $\mu$ in (5) should be a $kT\log(z)$, right? Of course, $\mu$ is the standard notation for the chemical potential, but you're already using this symbol for the probability measure...

Comment: @YvanVelenik yes, $\mu$ is a bad notation for the chemical potential in my case. Thanks for your comments. Following the canonical case, it is probably also a good idea to define $S(\mu) = -\infty$ when $\mu$ has not the form of (\ref{2}), right?

Comment: Yes. The measure has to be absolutely continuous wrt to the underlying Poisson point process.

Comment: @YvanVelenik I did the calculations and my reasoning seems to lead to the right result. The only point is that there is a factor $1/N!$ missing. Should I simply define the counting measure $\delta(\{N\}) = 1/N!$ instead? This solves the problem, but it seems a bit artificial to me.

Comment: It’s not artificial : the points are indistinguishable, we number them for convenience, but the numbering is meaningless. The "1/N!" is implicit in the definition of the Poisson point process, which is why you don’t see it in the paper I linked.

Comment: @YvanVelenik my point is that I can define the counting measure $\delta$ as I want, and it seems that the solution of (\ref{5}) changes accordingly. There must be some deeper reason why $\delta(\{N\}) = 1/N!$ and not something else.

Comment: I think the problem is with definition (\ref{2}). It should be a probability measure, and it is not normalized as it is. But the factor $1/N!$ does not normalize it either, does it? This is the only thing missing, I think.

Comment: Well, (2) is normalized properly if you ask that $\rho$ has integral $1$ wrt to what you denote $d\delta dx$. The issue of the $1/N!$ is the usual one in equilibrium statistical mechanics. The point is that microscopic configurations associated with your system of particles is an (unordered) set of points in $\mathbb{R}^d$. So when integrating over $\Omega_N$, you are counting each configuration $N!$ times, which requires correcting by $1/N!$. But this is just one instance of the standard "Gibbs paradox" issue, which everbody has a different justification for.